# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: current(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array

Tags: php

I got a fatal error when I'm creating a template for my practiced website and I don't get it how can I rid this error.

**This is the fatal error I get when I run it:**

"Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: current(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShawpifyV5\inc\template.php:52 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ShawpifyV5\inc\template.php(52): current(NULL) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ShawpifyV5\inc\template.php(78): Template->output() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShawpifyV5\inc\template.php on line 52"

**And this is the picture of my code in template.php:**

[image]

**This is the actual codes in my template.php:**

```
$contentExample = array (   
    array(
        "name" => "First Product",
        "price" => "Php.39,999.99",
        "description" => "This is a short discription. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Second Product",
        "price" => "Php.50,000.00",
        "description" => "This is a short discription. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Third Product",
        "price" => "Php.45,875.00",
        "description" => "This is a short discription. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Fourth Product",
        "price" => "Php.400,000.00",
        "description" => "This is a short discription. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Fifth Product",
        "price" => "Php.599,000.99",
        "description" => "This is a short discription. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Sixth Product",
        "price" => "Php.300,000.00",
        "description" => "This is a short discription. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
    )
);


class Template {

    private $template;
    private $content;

    public function _construct($template,$content) {

        //Should validate arguments before we continue
        $this->load($template,$content);

    }

    public function output(){

        $record = current($this->content);
        $html = $this->template;
        
        foreach ($record as $key => $value) {
            # code...

            $html = str_replace($html,$value,"{".$key."}");

        }
    
        return $html;

    }

    public function load($template,$content) {

        $this->template = file_get_contents("http://localhost/shawpifyv5/templates/$template",true);
        //$this->template = $template;
        $this->content = $content;

    }

}

$test = new Template("product_thumbnail.html",$contentExample);

echo $test->output();
```

Comment: you are not setting `$this->content` in your constructor. Use: `$this->content = $content;` inside `__construct()`. And make sure the content is of type array (you can test it by `var_dump()` ing the variable). Also, do not use pictures of your code, read [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Why are you using URL in `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: First of all, please paste your code as text. I can't copy and test screenshots...

Comment: @berend The constructor calls `load` which sets `$this->content = $content;`. The issue is probably just that it isn't an array. @John You could add type hinting to your parameters to make sure you get an array. Though you should probably run additional validation, such as it not being empty.

Comment: @KarolDabrowski I already posted the codes. I hope you can help me to get rid this error.

Comment: I appreciated you all, for helping me. I hope I can get rid this error. I learning new stuff because of you all. advance thank you for you all.

Comment: as noted by @El_Vanja apparently you are setting `$this->content` using `load`, I missed that because it's hard reading code from a picture... however, the real issue is, as the `var_dump()` shows that you are not feeding function `current()` with an array.

Comment: @berend I tried what you said I put the `$this->content = $content;` inside the `_construct()`, but still the same error in line 52. I tried also the `var_dump()` and this is what I get **"object(Template)#1 (2) { ["template":"Template":private]=> NULL ["content":"Template":private]=> NULL }"**. It's pretty interesting using `var_dump()`.

Comment: My mind went in the wrong direction for a moment there... it seems you've dumped the entire instance (`$this`). Try dumping only `$content` inside the constructor.

Comment: There is no result came out when I dumping the `$content`

Comment: Oh dear lord... I've only now noticed. You need another underscore for the constructor method. You're using `_construct` which is then treated as a regular function. It needs to be `__construct` to actually act as a constructor.

Comment: Now, the next problem you're going to run into is the wrong parameter order in your `str_replace` call. Consult the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace).

Comment: @El_Vanja. Thank for the help. I need to remember the diffence using this "`__`" to this "_". I appreciated you all. I learned new things to you all. Thank you guys.

Comment: I already notice that. It should be `$html = str_replace("{".$key."}",$value,$html);`. It's running. Thank you @El_Vanja. How should I rate you? Because I appreciated you the most.

Comment: and also I want to thank you @berend.

Comment: No need to rate. The policy is that questions where the problem turns out to be a typo should be removed instead of answered (as they're unlikely to help others). Don't worry about it. Glad to have helped and good luck with the rest of your project.